# SQL: Unknown column 'items.id' Relationship Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have issues with this query. I think the issue is with not finding the **`items`**. Afterwards I am doing LEFT OUTER JOIN on it but before that nothing. What is the best solution to include the items table in the beginning ?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` FROM (`categories_items`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `items_stones` `items_stones` ON `items`.`id` = `items_stones`.`item_model_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `items` ON `items`.`id` = `categories_items`.`item_model_id` 
WHERE ( `items_stones`.`stone_model_id` = 1 ) AND `categories_items`.`category_model_id` = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to be like below, basically swap the `LEFT JOINS`

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` 
    FROM `categories_items` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `items` ON `items`.`id` = `categories_items`.`item_model_id`
   AND `categories_items`.`category_model_id` = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `items_stones` ON `items`.`id` = `items_stones`.`item_model_id` 
 AND `items_stones`.`stone_model_id` = 1;
```